# How to download google_services.json file of an existing project?

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin, google-play-services

I am trying to download the google_services.json file for an existing android project but I am not able to do so. 
I have also read the documentation from the following link:

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en#android

but couldn't find it helpful as I could not find the download icon on the console as told by them.

So anyone having better suggestions. Please share and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link to download the google_services.json
[google service json](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In)

Answer (score 0):

you can this [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue) for json file

Answer (score 0):

Goto link https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In

**Login and choose your app**

> Click on Choose and configure services

[image]

**Step:2 Click on Configuration files**

[image]

**step 3 Download the file**

[image]